# decorate xml subtree with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to transform this xml tree

```
<doc>
  <a>
    <op>xxx</op>
  </a>
</doc>
```

to

```
<doc>
  <a>
    <cls>
      <op>xxx</op>
    </cls>
  </a>
</doc>
```

I use this python code

```
from lxml import etree
f = etree.fromstring('<doc><a><op>xxx</op></a></doc>')

node_a = f.xpath('/doc/a')[0]
ele = etree.Element('cls')
node_a.insert(0, ele)

node_cls = f.xpath('/doc/a/cls')[0]
node_op = f.xpath('/doc/a/op')[0] 
node_cls.append(node_op) 
print etree.tostring(f, pretty_print=True)
```

Is it the best solution ?

Now I want to obtain

```
<cls>
  <doc>
    <a>
      <op>xxx</op>    
    </a>
  </doc>
</cls>
```

I am unable to find any solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the first case I want to add <cls> </cls> arround <op> xxx </op>. In the second case I want to add <cls> </cls> arround <doc> ... </doc>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) better than [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml). I find it easier to handle.

Both problems can be solved using the same approach, first find the element, get its parent, create the new element and put the old one inside it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'xml')
for e in soup.find_all(sys.argv[2]):
    p = e.parent
    cls = soup.new_tag('cls')
    e_extracted = e.extract()
    cls.append(e_extracted)
    p.append(cls)

print(soup.prettify())
```

The script accepts two arguments, thr first one is the `xml` file and second one the tag to surround with new tag. Run it like:

```
python3 script.py xmlfile op
```

That yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
 <a>
  <cls>
   <op>
    xxx
   </op>
  </cls>
 </a>
</doc>
```

For `<doc>`, run it like:

```
python3 script.py xmlfile doc
```

With following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cls>
 <doc>
  <a>
   <op>
    xxx
   </op>
  </a>
 </doc>
</cls>
```